# Multiple Master pages for multiple solution Issue[master pages can create from one particular system]

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have multiple solutions for one asp.net website project. each solution refers different master page. Master pages located in some other solution. we call the master page in page

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            MasterPageFile = clsVirtualPathProvider.LoginMasterFileLocation;
            base.OnPreInit(e);
        }
```

The problem here is, the master page created is not from my system. its created from other system. if i will create and use new master page,then it will work in my system. not in other system. In others system it will go to `500 Internal server error.`  is there any solutions pls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by doing following:
1. go to particular master page right click and select properties
2. change Build action to Embedded Resource